# Почему результат добавления атрибутов в другой класс одинаковый? Отзывы должны быть разными в объектах класса Книга?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, append

```
class Book:
    list_of_reviews = []
    def __init__(self,info_about_author,year_of_publication,genre,publisher):
        self.info_about_author = info_about_author
        self.year_of_publication = year_of_publication
        self.genre = genre
        self.publisher = publisher

    def __str__(self):
        author = 'Author: ' + self.info_about_author
        year = 'Year of publication: ' + self.year_of_publication
        genre = 'Genre: ' + self.genre
        publisher = 'Name of publisher: ' + self.publisher
        reviews = 'Reviews about book: ' + '\n' + '\n'.join(self.list_of_reviews)
        return author + '\n' + year + '\n' + genre + '\n' + publisher + '\n' + reviews
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
    def __eq__(self,other):
        if str(self) is str(other):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def __ne__(self,other):
        if repr(self) is not repr(other):
            return True
        else:
            return False
class Book_review:
    def __init__(self,review):
        self.review = review
    def add_review(self,obj): #метод добавления в список отзывов объекта класса Книга
        obj.list_of_reviews.append(self.review)
book1 = Book('Pete Barker','2007','Historical genre','Hamish Hamilton')
book2 = Book('Aldous Huxley','1932','Science fiction','Harper Collins')
review1 = Book_review('Brave New World explores the negatives of a ostensibly successful world in which everyone appears to be content and satisfied, with excessive carnal pleasures yet really, this stability is only achieved by sacrificing freedom in its true sense and the idea of personal responsibility.')
review2 = Book_review('It is true that this book is a complex read and I must confess that some parts I did not understand; however, the novels meaning has left a deep impression on me. Its certainly a book I wont forget,and I would recommend it to readers aged fourteen and over as the ideas presented are complex, and Huxley writes in a very adult-like manner, with exceedingly complicated sentences and very complex vocabulary.')
review1.add_review(book2) #должно добавлять отзывы только в этот объект
review2.add_review(book2)
print(str(book1))
print(str(book2))
print(repr(book1))
print(repr(book2))
print(book1 == book2)
print(book2 != book2)
```

Comment: А в чем ошибка? То, что список ревью для book1 и book2 присутствует, хотя ревью было только для одной книги?

Comment: @gil9red да, проблема в том, что ревью для book1 и book2 одинаковий, хотя список ревью для book1 должен быть пустым

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Измените класс так:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, info_about_author, year_of_publication, genre, publisher):
        self.list_of_reviews = []
        self.info_about_author = info_about_author
        self.year_of_publication = year_of_publication
        self.genre = genre
        self.publisher = publisher

    ...
```

---

А теперь почему так произошло. Есть класс, а есть объект. Например, у вас есть класс `Book`, а есть объекты `book1` и `book2`.

То, как вы описали свойство:

```
class Book:
    list_of_reviews = []
    ...
```

Является созданием свойства у класса. А т.к. класс общий для всех объектов, то, соответственно, свойство `list_of_reviews` было общим для всех книг

---

Эту особенность можно обойти, если изменить ссылку на объект свойства класса у самого объекта:

```
class Book:
    list_of_reviews = None

    def __init__(self, info_about_author, year_of_publication, genre, publisher):
        self.list_of_reviews = []
        ...
```

Тогда, у каждого нового объекта, будет свое свойство.

---

##### UPD. Есть способ упростить создание класса с конструктором, аннотацией полей, механизмом сравнения и методом строкового описания объектов через [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

*Для аннотации от встроенных типов типа `list[str]` нужен python 3.10 и выше, для ранних версий, его можно заменить на `List` из `typing`.*

Переписал код:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Book:
    info_about_author: str
    year_of_publication: str
    genre: str
    publisher: str
    list_of_reviews: list[str] = field(default_factory=list, repr=False)
    
    def print_info(self):
        print(self)

book1 = Book('Pete Barker','2007','Historical genre','Hamish Hamilton')
print(book1)
# Book(info_about_author='Pete Barker', year_of_publication='2007', genre='Historical genre', publisher='Hamish Hamilton')

book1.print_info()
# Book(info_about_author='Pete Barker', year_of_publication='2007', genre='Historical genre', publisher='Hamish Hamilton')
```